# How to convert JSON data inside a pandas column into new columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have this short version of ADSB json data and would like to convert it into dataFrame columns as Icao, Alt, Lat, Long, Spd, Cou.....

After Alperen told me to do this

```
df = pd.read_json('2016-06-20-2359Z.json', lines=True),
```

I can load it into a DataFrame. However, `df.acList` is

```
[{'Id': 10537990, 'Rcvr': 1, 'HasSig': False, ...
Name: acList, dtype: object
```

How can I get the Icao, Alt, Lat, Long, Spd, Cou data?

```json
 "src":1,
   "feeds":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "name":"ADSBexchange.com",
         "polarPlot":false
      }
   ],
   "srcFeed":1,
   "showSil":true,
   "showFlg":true,
   "showPic":true,
   "flgH":20,
   "flgW":85,
   "acList":[  
      {  
         "Id":11281748,
         "Rcvr":1,
         "HasSig":false,
         "Icao":"AC2554",
         "Bad":false,
         "Reg":"N882AS",
         "FSeen":"\/Date(1466467166951)\/",
         "TSecs":3,
         "CMsgs":1,
         "AltT":0,
         "Tisb":false,
         "TrkH":false,
         "Type":"CRJ2",
         "Mdl":"2001 
BOMBARDIER INC 
 CL-600-2B19",
         "Man":"Bombardier",
         "CNum":"7503",
         "Op":"EXPRESSJET AIRLINES INC - ATLANTA, GA",
         "OpIcao":"ASQ",
         "Sqk":"",
         "VsiT":0,
         "WTC":2,
         "Species":1,
         "Engines":"2",
         "EngType":3,
         "EngMount":1,
         "Mil":false,
         "Cou":"United States",
         "HasPic":false,
         "Interested":false,
         "FlightsCount":0,
         "Gnd":false,
         "SpdTyp":0,
         "CallSus":false,
         "TT":"a",
         "Trt":1,
         "Year":"2001"
      },
      {  
         "Id":11402205,
         "Rcvr":1,
         "HasSig":true,
         "Sig":110,
         "Icao":"ADFBDD",
         "Bad":false,
         "FSeen":"\/Date(1466391940977)\/",
         "TSecs":75229,
         "CMsgs":35445,
         "Alt":8025,
         "GAlt":8025,
         "AltT":0,
         "Call":"TEST1234",
         "Tisb":false,
         "TrkH":false,
         "Sqk":"0262",
         "Help":false,
         "VsiT":0,
         "WTC":0,
         "Species":0,
         "EngType":0,
         "EngMount":0,
         "Mil":true,
         "Cou":"United States",
         "HasPic":false,
         "Interested":false,
         "FlightsCount":0,
         "Gnd":true,
         "SpdTyp":0,
         "CallSus":false,
         "TT":"a",
         "Trt":1
      }
   ],
   "totalAc":4231,
   "lastDv":"636019887431643594",
   "shtTrlSec":61,
   "stm":1466467170029
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you already have your data in `acList` column in a pandas DataFrame, simply do:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.acList[0])

Alt AltT    Bad CMsgs   CNum    Call    CallSus Cou EngMount    EngType ... Sqk TSecs   TT  Tisb    TrkH    Trt Type    VsiT    WTC Year
0   NaN 0   False   1   7503    NaN False   United States   1   3   ...     3   a   False   False   1   CRJ2    0   2   2001
1   8025.0  0   False   35445   NaN TEST1234    False   United States   0   0   ... 0262    75229   a   False   False   1   NaN 0   0   NaN
```

Since pandas 1.0 the imports should be:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.json_normalize(df.acList[0])
```

Comment: This is on Python 2.7, right? I am not able to do it on Python 3. Would you please help me with that?

Comment: @Hamid  This is Python 3. If you're having problems with your code post it to SO, tag with `Pandas`, `json` or whatsoever and we will try to help you. Cheers!

Comment: What if one or more than one rows has `None` , meaning no data available for some records?

Comment: @Regressor you can solve by replacing `None` by `{}`, can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62862747/7385033)

Answer (score 24):

@Sergey's answer solved the issue for me but I was running into issues because the json in my data frame column was kept as a string and not as an object.  I had to add the additional step of mapping the column:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.acList.apply(json.loads))
```

Comment: Thank you worked for my case, where I had JSON data in the 1st column, and I wanted to transpose it to other columns

Comment: This works, but what if I have this column that I am converting into multiple, in addition to other columns that I want to keep as-is (they are regular columns). How can I achieve this?

Comment: not sure and I don't really have a pandas env setup anymore to check but maybe you can search for a 'flatMap' function?

Answer (score 7):

Since [pandas 1.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html), json_normalize is available in the top-level namespace.
Therefore use:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.json_normalize(df.acList[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment yet on ThinkBonobo's answer but in case the JSON in the column isn't exactly a dictionary you can keep doing `.apply` until it is. So in my case

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

json_normalize(
    df
    .theColumnWithJson
    .apply(json.loads)
    .apply(lambda x: x[0]) # the inner JSON is list with the dictionary as the only item
)
```

Comment: Useful contribution. 
On my data in Panda 0.24.2 the last line is not required. 
This may be specific to your data. I.e. mine looks like {'key':value} Perhaps yours looks like [{'key':value}]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had some missing values (`None`) then I created a more specific code that also drops the original column after creating the new ones:

```py
for prefix in ['column1', 'column2']:
    df_temp = df[prefix].apply(lambda x: {} if pd.isna(x) else x)
    df_temp = pd.io.json.json_normalize(df_temp)
    df_temp = df_temp.add_prefix(prefix + '_')
    df.drop([prefix], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df = pd.concat([df, df_temp], axis = 1, sort=False)
```