# How to split column with dictionary into 2 column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to split the following column into a data frame with column with the name of every country and the other two columns with the data from the first column (history)?

From this dataframe:

```
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+------------------------------+
| coordinates                             | country                          | country_code   | history                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |   latest | province                     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+------------------------------|
| {'lat': '15', 'long': '101'}            | Thailand                         | TH             | {'1/22/20': 0, '1/23/20': 0, '1/24/20': 0, '1/25/20': 0, '1/26/20': 0, '1/27/20': 0, '1/28/20': 0, '1/29/20': 0, '1/30/20': 0, '1/31/20': 0, '2/1/20': 0, '2/10/20': 0, '2/11/20': 0, '2/12/20': 0, '2/13/20': 0, '2/14/20': 0, '2/15/20': 0, '2/16/20': 0, '2/17/20': 0, '2/18/20': 0, '2/19/20': 0, '2/2/20': 0, '2/20/20': 0, '2/21/20': 0, '2/22/20': 0, '2/23/20': 0, '2/24/20': 0, '2/25/20': 0, '2/26/20': 0, '2/27/20': 0, '2/28/20': 0, '2/29/20': 0, '2/3/20': 0, '2/4/20': 0, '2/5/20': 0, '2/6/20': 0, '2/7/20': 0, '2/8/20': 0, '2/9/20': 0, '3/1/20': 1, '3/10/20': 1, '3/11/20': 1, '3/12/20': 1, '3/13/20': 1, '3/14/20': 1, '3/15/20': 1, '3/16/20': 1, '3/2/20': 1, '3/3/20': 1, '3/4/20': 1, '3/5/20': 1, '3/6/20': 1, '3/7/20': 1, '3/8/20': 1, '3/9/20': 1}                                                                                                                                            |        1 |                              |
| {'lat': '36', 'long': '138'}            | Japan                            | JP             | {'1/22/20': 0, '1/23/20': 0, '1/24/20': 0, '1/25/20': 0, '1/26/20': 0, '1/27/20': 0, '1/28/20': 0, '1/29/20': 0, '1/30/20': 0, '1/31/20': 0, '2/1/20': 0, '2/10/20': 0, '2/11/20': 0, '2/12/20': 0, '2/13/20': 1, '2/14/20': 1, '2/15/20': 1, '2/16/20': 1, '2/17/20': 1, '2/18/20': 1, '2/19/20': 1, '2/2/20': 0, '2/20/20': 1, '2/21/20': 1, '2/22/20': 1, '2/23/20': 1, '2/24/20': 1, '2/25/20': 1, '2/26/20': 2, '2/27/20': 4, '2/28/20': 4, '2/29/20': 5, '2/3/20': 0, '2/4/20': 0, '2/5/20': 0, '2/6/20': 0, '2/7/20': 0, '2/8/20': 0, '2/9/20': 0, '3/1/20': 6, '3/10/20': 10, '3/11/20': 15, '3/12/20': 16, '3/13/20': 19, '3/14/20': 22, '3/15/20': 22, '3/16/20': 27, '3/2/20': 6, '3/3/20': 6, '3/4/20': 6, '3/5/20': 6, '3/6/20': 6, '3/7/20': 6, '3/8/20': 6, '3/9/20': 10}                                                                                                                                    |       27 |
```

into this:

```
 country  days    values
Thailand  1/2/22     0
Thailand  2/2/22     0
Thailand  2/2/22     0
....
Sweden    3/4/55     0
Sweden    3/4/55     0
```

Comment: Do not post Pic

Comment: why? i dont mind to show it

Comment: We use pd.read_clipboard in order to copy your dataframe and help you

Comment: Just updated it thanks for your interest

Comment: please could you check my answer?

Comment: Sorry will tell tomorrow, i disconnected, 11h working...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391291/how-to-convert-json-data-inside-a-pandas-column-into-new-columns/46391716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```
new_df = (pd.DataFrame(df['history'].tolist(),
                       index = df['country'])
             .reset_index()
             .melt('country',var_name = 'days')
             .sort_values('country'))
```

or symply:

```
#import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(data = np.concatenate([[(k, v) for k, v in d.items()] 
                                    for d in df['history']]),
             columns = ['days','values'],
            index = df['country'].repeat(df['history'].str.len())).reset_index()
```

**Example**

```
print(df)
  country  country_code       history
0       A             0  {1: 0, 2: 0}
1       B             1  {1: 0, 2: 0}
2       C             2  {1: 0, 2: 0}
```

---

```
new_df = (pd.DataFrame(df['history'].tolist(),
                       index = df['country'])
             .reset_index()
             .melt('country',var_name = 'days',value_name='values')
             .sort_values('country'))
print(new_df)
  country days  values
0       A    1       0
3       A    2       0
1       B    1       0
4       B    2       0
2       C    1       0
5       C    2       0
```

maybe second method is better

```
%%timeit
pd.DataFrame(data = np.concatenate([[(k,v) for k,v in d.items()] 
                                    for d in df['history']]),
             columns = ['days','values'],
            index = df['country'].repeat(df['history'].str.len())).reset_index()
1.71 ms ± 137 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
new_df = (pd.DataFrame(df['history'].tolist(),
                       index = df['country'])
             .reset_index()
             .melt('country',var_name = 'days')
             .sort_values('country'))
new_df
5.01 ms ± 272 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer and then KeyError 'history' because "newdf = pd.DataFrame(data=np.conc....." this trying the simply method (fastest)

Comment: Sorry was wrong, at the end the error is just "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: Thanks just had to cast to dataframe my data sorry, you saved my life, so kind ;)

Comment: By the way, how can i add the province column? forgot to mention it