# How can I split a pandas column containing a json into new columns in a given dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, string, dataframe

I am looking to split a dataframe column that contains a string of a dictionary into separate columns. I've seen a few methods, but I want to avoid splitting the string since there are some inconsistencies. For instance, "Melting Point" sometimes takes the place of "Boiling Point", but I do not want melting point and boiling point to be in the same column.

Here is the column I am trying to split.

[Json within Pandas Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGZCE.png)

```
#example below
data = [
'''[{'name': 'Boiling Point', 'property': '115.3 °C', 'sourceNumber': 1}]''',
'''[{'name': 'Boiling Point', 'property': '91 °C @ Press: 20 Torr', 'sourceNumber': 1}]''',
'''[{'name': 'Boiling Point', 'property': '58 °C @ Press: 12 Torr', 'sourceNumber': 1}, {'name': 'Density', 'property': '0.8753 g/cm<sup>3</sup> @ Temp: 20 °C', 'sourceNumber': 1}]''']
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['experimental_properties'])
```

I want it to look like this first row:

[Expected Output row 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3VKg.png)

I tried a method from here to no avail: [How to convert JSON data inside a pandas column into new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391291/how-to-convert-json-data-inside-a-pandas-column-into-new-columns)

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.experimental_properties.apply(json.loads))
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've understood your question well. Try:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df["experimental_properties"] = df["experimental_properties"].apply(
    lambda x: {d["name"]: d["property"] for d in literal_eval(x)}
)
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("experimental_properties").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            Boiling Point                                Density
0                115.3 °C                                    NaN
1  91 °C @ Press: 20 Torr                                    NaN
2  58 °C @ Press: 12 Torr  0.8753 g/cm<sup>3</sup> @ Temp: 20 °C
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the expected output really what you are looking for? Another way to visualise the data would be to have "name", "property", and "sourceNumber" as column names.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = [
'''[{'name': 'Boiling Point', 'property': '115.3 °C', 'sourceNumber': 1}]''',
'''[{'name': 'Boiling Point', 'property': '91 °C @ Press: 20 Torr', 'sourceNumber': 1}]''',
'''[{'name': 'Boiling Point', 'property': '58 °C @ Press: 12 Torr', 'sourceNumber': 1}, {'name': 'Density', 'property': '0.8753 g/cm<sup>3</sup> @ Temp: 20 °C', 'sourceNumber': 1}]''']

#Initialise a naiveList
naiveList = []

#String to List
for i in data:
    tempStringOfData = i
    tempStringOfData = tempStringOfData.replace("\'", "\"")
    tempJsonData = json.loads(tempStringOfData)
    naiveList.append(tempJsonData)

#Initialise a List for Dictionaries
newListOfDictionaries = []
for i in naiveList:
    for j in i:
        newListOfDictionaries.append(j)

df = pd.DataFrame(newListOfDictionaries)
print(df)
```

Which gives you

```
            name                               property  sourceNumber
0  Boiling Point                               115.3 °C             1
1  Boiling Point                 91 °C @ Press: 20 Torr             1
2  Boiling Point                 58 °C @ Press: 12 Torr             1
3        Density  0.8753 g/cm<sup>3</sup> @ Temp: 20 °C             1
```

Comment: The issue is that for some records, it repeats. For instance, the following record would need to have one column titled boiling point with 58 °C @ Press: 12 Torr as a value, and Density with 0.8753 g/cm<sup>3</sup> @ Temp: 20 °C as a value:'''[{'name': 'Boiling Point', 'property': '58 °C @ Press: 12 Torr', 'sourceNumber': 1}, {'name': 'Density', 'property': '0.8753 g/cm<sup>3</sup> @ Temp: 20 °C', 'sourceNumber': 1}]''']